# simplest possible test for output binding not working

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing

I am testing a dead simple component with one button. When button is clicked it emits an `(@output)` event is emitted and then parent's callback (`chatMessageFeedbackHandler`) is called. Nothing out of ordinary.

But for some reason the following test is not working. I am just testing if  parent's `chatMessageFeedbackHandler` is called when child's `button#test1` is clicked.

Note: If you comment either one of the following tests work successfully:

1. LINE: child 1.1 and child 1.2
2. LINE: parent 1.1 and parent 1.2

**Test:**

```
import {async, ComponentFixture, fakeAsync, flushMicrotasks, TestBed, tick} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {Component, DebugElement} from "@angular/core";
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {By} from '@angular/platform-browser';

function createHostComponent(): ComponentFixture<HostComponent> {
  const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HostComponent);
  fixture.detectChanges();
  return fixture as ComponentFixture<HostComponent>;
}

fdescribe('AppComponent', () => {
  let component: AppComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HostComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [HostComponent, AppComponent],
    })
    // .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    // fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ChatFeedbackComponent);
    fixture = createHostComponent();

  });

  fit('should emit chatMessageFeedback$ true when clicked on like button', fakeAsync(() => {
    const appComponent = fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(AppComponent)) as DebugElement;
    // spyOn(appComponent.componentInstance,'chatFeedbackClicked');//LINE: parent 1.1
    spyOn(fixture.componentInstance,'outputHandler'); //LINE: child 1.1
    fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#test1').click();
    tick(500);
    flushMicrotasks();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    // expect(appComponent.componentInstance.chatFeedbackClicked).toHaveBeenCalled();//LINE: parent 1.2
    expect(fixture.componentInstance.outputHandler).toHaveBeenCalledWith(true);//LINE: child 1.2
  }));

});


@Component({selector: 'host-for-test', template: `
    <app-root (chatMessageFeedback$)="outputHandler($event)"></app-root>
  `})
class HostComponent {

  outputHandler(data) {
    alert();
  }
}
```

**Child Component:**

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <button id="test1" (click)="chatFeedbackClicked(true)">Test</button>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  @Output() chatMessageFeedback$ = new EventEmitter();

  chatFeedbackClicked(isFeedbackPositive: boolean) {
    this.chatMessageFeedback$.emit(isFeedbackPositive);
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the scope of the test? To test that the child template component emits a value, or that when the parent host component, calls the actual function, when the child emits?

Comment: second one: *parent host component, calls the actual function, when the child emits*

Answer (score 0):

To test the following *parent host component, calls the actual function, when the child emits* , i think that you're tackling the problem from the wrong end.

In your case you need to mock, the template component (the child, app-chat-feedback component), and triggers the event fire manually (not through the whole click process, that's the case for another unit test). Check the below, this should get you working.

This is the mock of the template component

```js
@Component({
    template: '',
    selector: 'app-chat-feedback'
})
export class ChatFeedbackComponentMock {


    @Output() chatMessageFeedback$: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

    // This will be the function that triggers the emit
    emitFeedback(value: any) {
        this.chatMessageFeedback$.emit(value);
    }
}
```

This is the component whose functionality you're testing, in this case, that the `chatFeedbackClicked` is called when the child emits an event. This is the real component.

```js
@Component({
    template:`
        // Your Logic here
        <app-chat-feedback (chatMessageFeedback$)="chatFeedbackClicked($event)"></app-chat-feedback>
    `
})
export class MyComponentUnderTest {
    chatFeedbackClicked() {
        // Your logic here
    }
}
```

This is the test definition.

```js
describe('MyComponentUnderTest', () => {

    let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponentUnderTest>;
    let component: MyComponentUnderTest;

    beforeEach(() => {
        // Register both the real component under test, and the mock component of the child
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [ ChatFeedbackComponentMock, MyComponentUnderTest]
        });

        // Get a handle to the component fixture, and the component instancce
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponentUnderTest);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
    });

    // Important that you have the fakeAsync wrapper function, since the EventEmmiter behaves asynchronously
    it('Should call chatFeedbackClicked when the chatMessageFeedback$ event is fired', fakeAsync(() => {

        // Get a handle of the instance of the child mock component (the template component that you're mocking)
        let child: ChatFeedbackComponentMock = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('app-chat-feedback')).componentInstance;  

        // Spy on the function of the component under test, that will be asserted
        spyOn(component, 'chatFeedbackClicked');

        // Call emit feedback with some value, on the child component. This will trigger an emit call
        child.emitFeedback('value');

        // Since the calls are asynchronous, (EventEmmitter behaves like an observable), we need to simulate passing of time
        tick();

        // Assert that the function was called with the passed value
        expect(component.chatFeedbackClicked).toHaveBeenCalledWith('value');
    }));
});
```

Read more about testing asynchronous functions [here](https://angular.io/guide/testing#async-test-with-fakeasync) and about `fakeAsync` wrapper function [here](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/fakeAsync)

Comment: Hey thanks but, I think you are redefining my problem which is not good. My question is why current piece of code not working. My question is Not whether I am following best practices or not. Plus what solution you have given is already part of my question.